# get page datacontext from listitemtemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, mvvm, binding

I am Working on an Windows Phone 8 app,

My page has a ViewModel as datacontext.

This ViewModel has 2 properties :
 - A List
 - A ICommand

The page contains a Listbox bound to the list in my ViewModel and a template for each items of this list. This template contains a button.

But once the ListBox is bound to the ViewModel list I don't know how to bind the button command to the ViewModel ICommand.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{Binding ElementName=YourList, path=DataContext.YourCommand}
```

Don't forget to pass the item as parameter if you want to use this item in your command. PassEventArgs= true;